# Palindrome predicate using prolog

Tags: list, prolog, palindrome

I'm new to Prolog, and I have an exercise which asks to make a palindrome predicate that returns a Boolean value?
This boolean is true if the list is Palindrome otherwise returns false

```
palindrom([X|Xs],bool) .
```

How I should do it ?

Comment: writing code would be a good start. we're not here to do your homework for you .... show what you've attempted (and NOT just a function call sample), and we'll (maybe) try help fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstly, it's not function it's a predicate, so 
 palindrom is like to compare list with the invert of it like L=[x,y,x], L1=[x,y,x] then you shoud invert list befor ,

**code**

```
palindrom(Xs):-palindrom(Xs,Xs,[]). % the second Xs is copy of Xs in input and [] is the auxliare
palindrom([],Xs,Xs).
palindrom([Y|Ys],Xs,Zs):- palindrom(Ys,Xs,[Y|Zs]).
```

version2

```
 palindrom(Xs) :- reverse(Xs,Xs).
```

Note :reverse/2 to invert list but in this predicate return boolean value because the second is an intput to invert list

**result**

```
| ?- palindrom([a,b,c]).
no

| ?- palindrom([a,b,a]).
yes
```

for more details use `?-trace,palindrom("radar").` to see how it's work inside

Comment: With the second solution ,  copy this  `:- use_module(library(lists)).` to export `reverse/2`

Comment: @hulk using `trace`, u can see how the predicate call itself or other predicates inside it recursively

Answer (score 2):

You can use a "declarative way" e.g.

The empty list is a palindrome.

```
palindrome([]).
```

A list with only one element is a palindrome

```
palindrome([_]).
```

Now, one can say that if a list is a palindrome, if we remove the first and the last element of this list we must find another palindrome, so

```
palindrome(L) :-
    append([X|T], [X], L),
    palindrome(T).
```